# callback from UITapGestureRecognizer to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

Когда для `UIView` назначается `UITapGestureRecognizer`, ему передается ссылка на `target` (кстати, подкажите, что это такое?) и селектор - ссылка на метод, вызываемый по нажатии на `UIView`.

Интересует возможность получить ссылку на `UIView` по которому был сделан Tap в теле метода, обрабатывающего клик на этот `UIView`. В андроиде это предусмотрено по умолчанию, как можно реализовать такое в iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документацию](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/view) пробовали читать?

1) таргет - это какой класс должен выполнить метод после нажатия (селектор - это какой метод в обозначенном выше классе надо выполнить)

2) у UIGestureRecognizer есть свойство view - это и есть к какому вью прицеплен рекогнайзер, соответственно тап приходится всегда на этот вью

Comment: ммм, мы можем цеплять любые методы к recognizer, как Class.func, Class.func(\_:), так и Clacc.func(\_:a:b:c:...n:), уже разобрался что если сделать функцию func(gestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer), то соответственно рекогнайзер привязаный к UIView передастся в функцию, что в общем то решает мою проблему. Но появляется вопрос - как это реализовано и что произойдет в других случаях? Нет ли документации на эту тему, которую можно изучить?